# Miner incentives in a permission blockchain with a digitally native asset on Ethereum?

Tags: ether, mining, fees, permissioned-chain

Would be very grateful if someone could give me their opinion and ideas on whether this is possible, and if so, how this might be done:

If one were to build a permission blockchain on Ethereum with it's own native coin, how could consensus be reached? And more importantly, how could miner incentives work in such a system? Miners could be internal or external to the system, but I wouldn't want the miners to interact with the utility token (unless internal to the system), albeit whether external or interna,they would receive the gas token as transactions fee fees from the blockchain users.

Tricky question... would appreciate your thoughts.